# DHCP Server Issuing same IP address to client

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, centos-5

Greeting Guru's

I am using CentOS DHCP and DNS Server. Recently, I have notice that the DHCP Server has been issuing multiple IP Address to same client (Phone/Laptop). This has caused IP Conflict in the network.

How to Correct this?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "issuing the same address to multiple clients" rather than "issuing multiple address to same client"? It's not impossible that two of your devices have the same MAC address, and I imagine the easiest to change would be the laptop.